# How to use UTC in JQuery UI datepicker Angular directive for setting the date?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the angular Jquery UI datepicker(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) for selecting the date of birth.

The datepicker correctly picks and displays time when I click on it. But, the value is saved as midnight of my current timezone(+0530).

For example, if the date `30/04/1981` is selected the actual model value: `1981-04-29T18:30:00.000Z`. I understand that this is the expected behaviour, but for the case of setting the dob, the value should not change from country to country.

Is there an elegant way to convert this value to `UTC 00.00:000z`? While preserving the date selected in the current time zone?

html is given below,

```
<div>
    <input ui-date="dateOptions"
           name="dob"
           ng-model="passenger.dob"
           class="form-control"/>
</div>
<p>{{passenger.dob}}</p>
```

`dateOptions` are as follows,

```
self.dateOptions = {
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: self.minDate,
    maxDate: self.maxDate,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    weekHeader: "Wk",
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png"
};
```

Comment: can you share some of your html part?

Comment: I've added html and js parts.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine here in my `punker`.. https://plnkr.co/edit/sBdu1J?p=preview

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't seem to be saved fully. Could you please re-check it?